# Definition a measure is bounded

Tags: measure-theory

I have:

> If $\mu$ is a finite measure on a ring $R$, and $\overline{\mu}$ is its unique extention to $\sigma(R)$, then $\overline{\mu}$ is finite if and only if $\mu$ is bounded.

My book doesn't define "$\mu$ is bounded", what does it mean and how does it differ from $\mu$ is finite?

Comment: I would take it to mean that $\mu$ is a bounded function in the usual sense:   $\exists M<\infty,\;\forall E \in R,\;|\mu(E)|<M$

Comment: But is this not equivalent to say that $\mu$ is finite, i.e. $\mu(E)<\infty$?

Comment: Could it happen that $\mu(E)<\infty$ for all $E \in R$, but $\sup_E \mu(E) = \infty$?

Comment: Yes, it can (e.g. the sequence of natural numbers). Ok I see your point.